# Can a piezoelectric inverter for CCFL work for similar sized neon tubes?

Tags: inverter, ccfl, neon

I've done some backlight work for instrument displays using CCFLs and designing custom drivers (12 Vdc to ~1000 Vac) so I have some experience with these designs.  Recently a friend of mine was interested in doing some custom neon controllers for small diameter, short length tubes ( < 1m).  Are the electrical characteristics for neon similar for CCFL?  Has anyone experimented with modifying piezoelectric inverters to drive neon lamps?

Comment: I believe they tend to be "quite similar", but, the exact values of X Y Z differ, depending on factors of tube diameter, length, gas, etc.    Before the tube is lit, applies X volts, Y mA at Z Hz. Voltage needs to be high, often few hundred to few thousand volts, depending on tube length, etc.  Current needs not be high. 

After tube is lit, voltage drops to A volts (typically tens of volts) and current-limited at B mA.  

Frequency can ranges from DC up to few tens of KHz. The V I (X, Y, A, B) characteristics varies a bit at different frequency.

Comment: Some information here.   neon-sign transformer …in the range of 2 to 15 kV ... 30 - 120 mA.

makes the transformer more of an AC constant current source than a constant voltage source  Modern neon sign "transformers" are typically switching power supplies designed to have similar characteristics to the older style of mains-frequency transformer. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon-sign_transformer
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109786/how-are-neon-sign-transformers-built

Comment: Some ready-made units with different voltage and current ratings.
5kv 25ma, 8kv 25ma, 4kv 50mA, 8kV 25mA, 990v 40ma
http://www.signbuyer.co.uk/neon-transformers-2-c.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a bit of research, and found this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2_MHAtbGyY

as well as several articles. It would appear that it is possible to drive neon tubes,although it may be slightly dim.

Comment: Thanks for the help in finding some examples.  I suspected it was possible, now I can look into the details of optimizing them.