# Does impedance limit the current in a transformer?

Tags: transformer, current-limiting, efficiency

High frequency is suitable for small transformers with ferrite core, but that causes high impedance.  Can we use that impedance to limit the current in a transformer of 1:1 ratio to 1 A without overheating or dissipation of energy?

Comment: Not sure what you want, but take a look at this EE.SE answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109786/how-are-neon-sign-transformers-built/109790#109790

Answer (score 1):

In a transformer, the inductance of each coil is measured as the inductance with the other coil forming an "open circuit."
When you short the secondary coil in a transformer, the inductance of the primary coil drops dramatically.

If I understand the intent of your question correctly, this is where your intended use of a "high impedance" (although it'd be correctly stated as "high reactance" or "high inductance") primary coil to limit overall transformer current flow will break down.
In order to limit the max. possible output current of your transformer to a certain value, the resistance (not reactance, just resistive losses) in the coils and the magnetic losses in the core+coupling between the two coils would have to be great enough to limit the current to that amount.
This would, unfortunately cause highly inefficient operation, high losses, and likely the overheating that you are wanting to avoid.

Comment: How do airgaps alter the behavior?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Honestly, I don't know much about the effets of airgaps in transformers yet. So far, the only reference I've seen to them in my research are a few references to airgaps being incorporated in the core material for flyback transformers, in order to add some reluctance.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB   i am really confused now so its the inductance and not the impedance right?

Comment: @saad The [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance) of a transformer is the combination of its [inductive reactance](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/ac-inductors.html) at the frequency of opteration, electrical resistance of the wire used in the windings, and several parasitics (ferro-magnetic heating/deforming of the core, magnetic hysteresis, inter-winding capacitance, etc.). While a transformer with a high enough resistive & parasitic impedance can indeed limit max. output current (due to losses), ...

Comment: ...if the majority of the impedance were simply from inductive reactance, then current-limiting on that basis would fail until you reach a high enough current to cause significant heating & efficiency losses, so it's not generally a useful method for current-limiting in a circuit.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB  here an experiment at (2:00) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCnI6ZOYKes   xl=2πfl please watch this video

Comment: @saad Please don't take this the wrong way, but my personal policy is that anything worth researching/studying is worth researching **in print**. While YouTube videos are great for entertainment & for watching demonstrations of things you've been researching, I doubt many of us here will agree to watch & comment on YouTube videos. Unfortunately, that often simply becomes a problem of debunking thousands (if not millions) of videos that are either negligently (or intentionally) spreading mis-information. If you can find a text-reference to what you're thinking, I'll happily read it & comment.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB not at all we are here to learn and share the information, here s a link i did found http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/formulae/inductance/inductor-inductive-reactance-formulae-calculations.php

Comment: @saad Yes, an inductor of fixed value can indeed limit the current in an AC circuit. If you added another inductor in series with your transformer, it could work in this sense. However, if you re-read the first section of my answer, I explained that the inductance of the primary coil in a transformer changes as a function of the impedance of the circuit attached to the sacondary coil. In a "perfect transformer" with 0 parasitics & 100% coupling, a shorted secondary coil would give the primary an inductance of 0. That is why I said the transformer itself wouldn't current-limit usefully.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance#Coupled_inductors_and_mutual_inductance

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB " **respond to current only by reactance. The magnitude of the reactance of an inductor rises in proportion to a rise in frequency, while the magnitude of the reactance of a capacitor decreases in proportion to a rise in frequency. As frequency goes up, inductive reactance goes up and capacitive reactance goes down.** "" [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance)

Comment: @saad that's absolutely correct, for an *ideal* inductor (no resistance/parasitics) with a *fixed* inductance. That's why I said a fixed inductor in series with the transformer would work for ac current limiting. *However*, that doesn't circumvent the problem of the mutual inductance between the primary & secondary coils in a transformer allowing one coil's current/load to change the "experienced inductance" of the other coil.

Comment: @saad Let's look at it a different way. Let's picture inductors as batteries. When you increase the current flowing through an inductor, magnetic energy is stored in the core, not dissimilar to charging a battery. Then, when you remove the current source, the inductor will discharge itself by forcing current to run through whatever circuit it can find/make to pass current through. Now, in a transformer, we've added a second set of terminals to the battery, but they're connected to the same core (so, in a way, to the same internal plates/electrolyte cells of our battery)...

Comment: ... now, when we "charge" the inductor by increasing the current passing through it, the circuit attached to the secondary (battery's other terminals) is discharging the magnetic energy as we're storing it on the primary. So, no matter how high an inductance (or how slow the charging speed of our battery) on our primary coil, if the secondary circuit is shorted, then all the energy is taken back out before we put any charge in, so the battery remains discharged & the inductor gives no impedance to the current, because the energy is being taken out as fast as we pump it in.

Comment: Well, I guess it'd be more reasonable to consider the magnetic core of the inductor as the battery & the coils as the battery's electrodes/terminals. ... But hopefully that makes this rather complex topic easier to "put into perspective," and make sense of.

Answer (score 0):

Impedance does limit transformer current. This impedance comprises copper resistance which wastes power and leakage inductance which does not waste power. In most transformers this impedance is very low so the short circuit current is very high like say 20 times the load current meaning that the transformer would burn out under prolonged short circuit conditions. These orthodox transformers have reasonably good load regulation. Transformers with high impedance can be realized by using magnetic shunts can have current limiting properties that give a sagging VI curve. Microwave ovens and battery chargers use these transformers.